# SQL select distinct value where Status = MAX

Tags: sql, select, max, distinct

I have a Table ErpInformations.

```
OrderId PartNo Status  
4711  |  1510 |  0  
4711  |  1511 |  0  
4711  |  1512 |  1  
4712  |  1513 |  3  
4712  |  1514 |  0  
4713  |  1515 |  0  
4713  |  1516 |  0
```

I want "select distinct" query that is showing me only the OrderIds with the maximum status one of the part has.

Result:

```
4711 | 1  
4712 | 3  
4713 | 0
```

Has somebody a solution?

My first try would be:

```
select distinct(OrderId), 
       (select max(Status) from ErpInformations) 
  from ErpInformations;
```

But of course I get the overall max status. How can I limit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `MAX` with `group by` directly

```
select OrderId,max(Status) 
from ErpInformations
group by OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with Group by Clause and Max Function.

```
SELECT ORDERID, MAX(STATUS) FROM ERPINFORMATIONS GROUP BY ORDERID;
```

The SQL script displays the distinct ORDERIDs with maximum status available.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to achieve the result

```
select OrderId,max(Status) from ErpInformations
group by OrderId
```